# how to split single string and build a StringArray and pass it to ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have String

> `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n\nProin rhoncus congue convallis. Quisque fermentum ipsum vitae mauris placerat hendrerit. Nunc ornare fermentum mi, eget blandit massa lobortis quis. Aenean lectus purus, tincidunt eu volutpat nec, malesuada viverra massa. Ut pulvinar tempor ultrices. Vestibulum varius elementum diam sit amet elementum. Phasellus semper tempor massa, non posuere sem semper quis. Aenean ut sem justo. In consequat eleifend magna, iaculis pulvinar dui tincidunt pulvinar. Nullam in est justo, sed sollicitudin eros.\n\nPraesent at ligula quam. Sed lobortis arcu ligula, nec tincidunt diam. Integer ultrices iaculis mi, aliquam rutrum neque pretium nec. Duis vitae orci nulla. Maecenas ac nisl et mauris iaculis ultricies. Aenean imperdiet viverra libero, et ullamcorper arcu scelerisque ut. Vestibulum metus tellus, venenatis in vehicula non, rutrum ut sem. Donec in purus at magna suscipit egestas. Curabitur felis metus, hendrerit nec fermentum nec, tempus condimentum massa. Morbi erat augue, sollicitudin id adipiscing at, porttitor sed ipsum. Duis non massa et elit condimentum cursus vel ut libero.\n\nSed cursus placerat turpis, a ornare turpis porttitor et. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris posuere condimentum sapien, eget facilisis mi faucibus iaculis. Maecenas vitae lectus augue. Pellentesque vitae orci purus. Cras egestas ante nulla. Sed tempus feugiat orci eget sollicitudin. Vestibulum eget risus justo. Etiam ipsum libero, pellentesque non gravida pellentesque, vehicula eget ligula. Etiam id purus massa, sit amet sagittis purus. Etiam sed mattis elit.\n\nIn hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ac pretium diam. Curabitur pharetra magna in mi posuere vulputate. Donec vitae sapien ante. Fusce fermentum diam tempor massa mattis sit amet malesuada metus ullamcorper. Phasellus elementum semper lectus, non adipiscing odio rutrum semper. Nam gravida, velit a blandit ultrices, quam massa consequat neque, sit amet malesuada eros leo eget turpis. Quisque sollicitudin elementum tempor. Maecenas elementum ornare justo, nec malesuada libero accumsan quis. Suspendisse eleifend arcu cursus nulla tincidunt id bibendum enim placerat. Donec eget porttitor nunc. Etiam quis lorem vel dolor interdum hendrerit vel id sapien. Nam ultrices tempus ipsum a dapibus.`

I want to this show text like this image see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZNRJ.jpg).
I am facing a problem because ViewPager takes array and creates view according to array size, but here I have a single object string. 
So how can i do this? Anyone experience with this?

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines to form a question [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [keypoints to enhance qulity of question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Simply add **breaks** (can be any unused string or character; ie: `"§§§"`) in your text ans split the string on that character (or sequence). It will produce an array, which is well accepted by the ViewPager. PROBLEM SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to split the string up yourself. The ViewPager doesn't know how to make this. Probably have it in a ScrollView or using [AutoSizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) to make sure all the text can be displayed no matter what screen it's rendered on.